# Creating button content, using rectangle's OpacityMaskProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I want to make a button with icon, using Rectangle:

```
    <Style x:Key="CancelButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Rectangle>
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <Canvas Width="76.0106" Height="76.0106" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76.0106,0L 76.0106,76.0106L 0,76.0106L 0,0">
                                <Path Width="34.8358" Height="32.9005" Canvas.Left="20.5862" Canvas.Top="20.5864" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource RedBrush}" Data="F1 M 25.3362,20.5864L 25.3348,29.2137C 28.5107,25.8499 33.0116,23.7507 38.0029,23.7507C 47.6232,23.7507 55.422,31.5494 55.422,41.1698C 55.422,45.9799 53.4723,50.3347 50.32,53.4869L 46.401,49.5679C 48.5503,47.4187 49.8796,44.4495 49.8796,41.1699C 49.8796,34.6106 44.5623,29.2932 38.003,29.2932C 34.4855,29.2932 31.3251,30.8224 29.1504,33.2522L 38.0029,33.2531L 33.2529,38.0031L 20.5862,38.0031L 20.5862,25.3364L 25.3362,20.5864 Z "/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I apply such style to the button, nothing happens. It doesn't work.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The Rectangle has no Fill.

Comment: @Clemens, I have set Fill, but that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Width`, `Height` and `Fill` properties of the `Rectangle`:

```
<Rectangle Width="76.0106" Height="76.0106" Fill="Gray">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas Width="76.0106" Height="76.0106" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76.0106,0L 76.0106,76.0106L 0,76.0106L 0,0">
                    <Path Width="34.8358" Height="32.9005" Canvas.Left="20.5862" Canvas.Top="20.5864" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Red" Data="F1 M 25.3362,20.5864L 25.3348,29.2137C 28.5107,25.8499 33.0116,23.7507 38.0029,23.7507C 47.6232,23.7507 55.422,31.5494 55.422,41.1698C 55.422,45.9799 53.4723,50.3347 50.32,53.4869L 46.401,49.5679C 48.5503,47.4187 49.8796,44.4495 49.8796,41.1699C 49.8796,34.6106 44.5623,29.2932 38.003,29.2932C 34.4855,29.2932 31.3251,30.8224 29.1504,33.2522L 38.0029,33.2531L 33.2529,38.0031L 20.5862,38.0031L 20.5862,25.3364L 25.3362,20.5864 Z "/>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thank you)) that helped. As @Clemens said, setting Fill was needed, too